# Why is my pineapple not growing bigger?

Tags: diagnosis, growth, fruits

I planted my pineapple about 5 years ago from the head of a store bought pineapple and even though it hasn't died and is still growing, it hasn't got nearly big enough to produce fruit or even approached the size I've seen other planted pineapples get.

About a year ago I planted it in a new pot with fresh soil and compost, it seemed to get a little better. I noticed what looked like smallish pineapples growing near the bottom. But beside that it's mostly still the same.

I water it as often as I can remember (usually every second or so day), and keep it in full sun. Is there anything I should be doing that I'm not?

[image: my pineapple]
[image: my pineapple]

Comment: Have you been fertilizing it? Container plants generally need fertilizer.

Comment: Nope, I have never fertilized it, so that could be the issue i guess 

Comment: Yeah, I think Colin is right about the nourishment. That's a long time to go without fertilizer. Compost is nice, but it's low in NPK. My favorite fertilizer for containers, so far, is plain old 24-8-16 All-purpose Miracle Gro (with some Epsom salt added initially). I'm sure there could be better ones, but it works for me with vegetables/herbs.

Comment: Just added some fertilizer! Will be annoying if the only reason that this hasn't grown at all in the last 7 years was something that simple 

Comment: I recommend fertilizing as often as the fertilizer label says you can do it for four weeks (maybe longer), unless the plant starts to decline because of it. You should notice much more dramatic results that way than if you only do it once in a while.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that!

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from your image that this plant has been struggling for some time; the fact that it is producing basal suckers means that it is reaching maturity and may never produce a stalk and fruit. The red colour in the leaves, together with the low count of leaves indicates that it has been looking for nourishment, possibly nitrogen, and may have arisen because it is root bound or simply in soil that is too poor to support a good crop.

Pineapple is a tropical epiphyte and needs to grow in a hot and humid environment in full sun; if it requires water every two days then that is a sign it is in dry air and will be most unhappy until the situation changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the plant needs more (deeper) potting soil!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, 7 years now and still the same size lol, but taking it out of full sun and now it's doing much better in terms of color.